# What makes its momentum to change?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

[image]

I was asking my self what makes the ball's momentum to change ?

A tenis ball falls down , then it touches a table and then it bounces back .

What makes the momentum of the ball changes ? it it the impulse of the contact (or reaction ) force $ N$ or the impulse of the gravity , or both of them  ?

Comment: This may be a simple question that would be off topic for this site, you need to demonstrte sufficient prior research in the question.
 The ball and table deform elastically (unless they break) the result behaving like a spring that exerts a force back upwards as they return towards their original shape.

Comment: Both, but one is much greater than the other usually.

Answer (score 1):

If time $t_B$ to time $t_A$ define the interval during which the ball is in contact with the table then the net upward force on the ball at some time $t$ during that interval is $(N(t) -mg)\hat j$.
So the impulse on the ball during the time of contact is $\int ^{t_A}_{t_B}(N(t)-mg)dt \hat j$ and that is the change in momentum $(p_A-p_B)\hat j$ during that time interval.

At other times over an interval of time $\Delta T$ the only force acting on the ball is the gravitational attraction $-mg \hat j$ and so during that time interval the impulse is $-mg \Delta T\hat j$ and that is the change in momentum during that time interval.

Adding together the two impulses and hence the two changes of momentum gives you the total change of momentum of the ball.